# Arrange X amount of things evenly around a point in 3d space

Tags: math, random, geometry

If I have X amount of things (lets just randomly say 300)

Is there an algorithm that will arrange these things somewhat evenly around a central point? Like a 100 sided dice or a 3d mesh of a sphere?

Id rather have the things somewhat evenly spaced like this..
[image]

Rather than this polar way..

[image]

ps. For those interested, wondering why do I want to do this?
Well I'm doing [these](http://adventofcode.com/) for fun, and after completing #7 I decided I'd like to represent the array of wires in 3d in Unity and watch them operate in a slowed down manner.

Comment: are you looking for something like that : https://sites.google.com/site/dlampetest/python/triangulating-a-sphere-recursively ?

Comment: yes.. Though I *dont think* it works for arbitrary numbers of points. I may just do the polar one as thats easy

Comment: yes the number of points is not arbitrary and i think it's not  possible   to cover any sphere with identical triangles

Comment: yeah, though i dont need identical at all. I Just want the very roughly equidistant

Comment: There's also the [`healpix`](http://healpix.sourceforge.net/) approach: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/427976/pdf.

Comment: You could try googling spherical fibonacci grid; there are at least some nice pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple transformation that maps a uniform sample in the rectangle `[0, 2 pi] x [-1, 1]` onto a uniform sample on the sphere of radius `r`:

```
T(phi, z) = (r cos(phi) sqrt(1 - z^2), r sin(phi) sqrt(1 - zˆ2), r z)
```

The reason why this transformation produces uniform samples on the sphere is that the area of any region `T(U)` obtained by transforming the region `U` from the rectangle does not depend on `U` but on the area of `U`.

To prove this mathematically it is enough to verify that the norm of the vectorial product

```
| ∂T/∂phi x ∂T/∂z |
```

is constant (the area on the sphere is the integral of this vectorial product w.r.t. `phi` and `z`).

**Summarizing**

To produce a random sample uniformly distributed in the Sphere of radius `r` do the following:

- Produce a random sample `(phi_1, ..., phi_n)` uniformly distributed in `[0, 2 pi]`.
- Produce a random sample `(z_1, ..., z_n)` uniformly distributed in `[-1, 1]`.
- For every pair `(phi_j, z_k)` calculate `T(phi_j, z_k)` using the formula above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a three-step approach. 1a) Make more points than you need. 1b) Remove some. 2) Adjust the rest.

1a) To make more points that you need, take any quasiregular polyhedron with sides that tessellate (triangles, squares, diamonds). Tesselate the spherical faces by subdivision, generating more vertices. For example, if you use the regular icosahedron you get geodesic domes. (Subdivide by 2, you get the dual to the C<sub>60</sub> buckyball.) Working out exact formulas isn't hard. The number of new vertices per face is quadratic in the subdivision.

1b) Randomly remove enough points to get you down to your target number.

2) Use a [force-directed layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) algorithm to redistribute the vertices over the sphere. The underlying force graph is just that provided by the nearest neighbors in your underlying tesselation.

There are other ways to do step 1), such as just generating random points in any distribution. There is an advantage of starting with a quasiregular figure, though. Force-directed algorithms have a reputation for poor convergence in some cases. By starting with something that's already mostly optimal, you'll bypass most all of any convergence problems you might have.

Answer (score 0):

One elegant solution I came across recently is a spherical fibonacci lattice (http://extremelearning.com.au/how-to-evenly-distribute-points-on-a-sphere-more-effectively-than-the-canonical-fibonacci-lattice/)
[image]

The nice thing about it is that you can specify the exact number of points you want

```
// C# Code example
Vector3[] SphericalFibonacciLattice(int n) {
  Vector3[] res = new Vector3[n];
  float goldenRatio = (1.0f + MathF.Sqrt(5.0f)) * 0.5f;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    float theta = 2.0f * MathF.PI * i / goldenRatio;
    float phi = MathF.Acos(1.0f - 2.0f * (i + 0.5f) / n);
    Vector3 p = new Vector3(MathF.Cos(theta) * MathF.Sin(phi),
                            MathF.Sin(theta) * MathF.Sin(phi),
                            MathF.Cos(phi));
    res[i] = p;
  }
  return res;
}
```

The linked article extends on this to create an even more uniform distribution, but even this basic version creates very nice results.