# Computationally picking a random point on a n-sphere

Tags: python, random

I need to randomly pick an n-dimensional vector with length 1. My best idea is to pick a random point in the sphere an normalize it:

```
import random

def point(n):
    sq = 0
    v = []
    while len(v) < n:
        x = 1 - 2*random.random()
        v.append(x)
        sq = sq + x*x
        if sq > 1:
            sq = 0
            v = []
    l = sq**(0.5)
    return [x / l for x in v]
```

The only problem is the  [volume of an n-ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#High_dimensions) gets smaller as the dimension goes up, so using a uniform distribution from `random.random` takes very long for even small n like 17. Is there a better (faster) way to get a random point on an n-sphere?

Comment: You can find the algorithm [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34402858/4081336).

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia Well, that algorithm only deals with n = 3

Comment: By randomly do you mean that it has to be uniformly distributed? These things get tricky pretty easily so I wouldn't bet that what you are doing now works in this sense.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html

Comment: @le_m the last paragraph is the winner! And Python has `random.gauss`.

Comment: @Bakuriu it is mathematically correct because I'm shaving a uniform cube to a uniform sphere using my if statement. I then project it onto the surface. But it is not correct because it doesn't halt even for small values.

Comment: YBerman, sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: please add the language tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Muller, M. E. "A Note on a Method for Generating Points Uniformly on N-Dimensional Spheres"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html) you would need to create a vector of n gaussian random variables and divide by its length:

```
import random
import math

def randnsphere(n):
  v = [random.gauss(0, 1) for i in range(0, n)]
  inv_len = 1.0 / math.sqrt(sum(coord * coord for coord in v))
  return [coord * inv_len for coord in v]
```

As stated by @Bakuriu in the comments, using `numpy.random` can offer you a performance advantage when working with larger vectors.

Comment: Respect for cutting back in division usage.

Comment: @YBerman I just edited that back in after removing it for perceived premature optimization ;)

Comment: You may consider using `numpy.random` to handle these vectors. It's probably mroe efficient.

Comment: You still have to reject points that are outside of the N-Dimensional sphere.
And also you are technically risking dividing by zero.